# Установка cookies в php

Tags: php, jquery

Читаю и устанавливаю куки со стороны фронтэнда я значит так:

```
notes = JSON.parse($.cookie(cookieName));
$.cookie(cookieName, JSON.stringify(notes), {expires: 30, path: '/'});
```

Где *notes* - это одномерный массив *var notes = []*.

Вопрос: как установить этот же массив в куки со стороны php, чтобы они читались jquery. Пробовал так:

```
setcookie($cookieName, json_encode($notes), time() + 3600, '/');
```

Не выходит

UPD: *$notes = array();*

Comment: Пробуйте `setcookie($cookieName, serialize(json_encode($notesTop)), time() + 3600, '/');`

Comment: Если с `json_encode()` не получится, то делайте без него. Когда вытащите, тогда и сделаете энкод. Кстати, при попытке чтения этой куки, перед чтением нужно таким же методом ансерилизовать массив, то есть так `$cook = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);`.